# How to dynamically add new values to a listbox using select2 in ASP .NET MVC 5 and pass it to the controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I am using select2 'tags:true' to add new values to an existing list box. But am unable to get the newly added value as it returns no value to the controller upon HttpPost. How can I get this newly added value in the controller?

**List Box code:**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedIds, Model.Categories, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "js-multiple" } )
```

**script section:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.js-multiple').select2({tags:true});});
```

Model.Categories fetches the values from the database and populates the listbox.
When I add a new value to the listbox and click on submit button (HttpPost), no values are passed to the controller. I want to pass the selected list items to the controller so that I can add the newly added value to the database.

Comment: I think you would need to add them to the actual select (not the select 2 version) and then destroy and re-initialise the select2 once the new values are added

Comment: How to add them to the actual select?

Answer (score 0):

you should get your data with ajax and set data to select2, look this example:

```
function GetCityBranch(provinceid) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Suppliers/Supplier/GetCity',
    data: { "provinceid": provinceid },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#BranchCityId").empty();

        array = data;
        $("#BranchCityId").select2({
            data: data
        });
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

}

Comment: So the addition of new values can't be achieved directly by using model property binded listbox?

Comment: It's better to use javascript to fill your dropdown with new value but you could use partial and put your dropdown in partial view without select2 you could refresh your model and just your partial refresh

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. :)